# Delete on cascade in Model Laravel with eloquent

Tags: sql-server, laravel

I want to delete data through the api but it is showing an error because it is necessary to delete records in the properties table.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server] The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Interests_Properties_User". The conflict occurred in database "CADASTRO", table "dbo.Interests_Properties", column 'interests_user_id'. (SQL: delete from [Interests_User] where [user_id] = 1515626)

I created the model that performs actions on the `Interests_Properts` table, but when I try to delete the data that has the same `interests_user_id`, errors are occurring.

##### `InterestsUser.php`:

```php
use App\Source\InterestsProperties;
    
class InterestsUser extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'sql_cadastro';
    protected $table = 'Interests_User';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function properties()
    {
        $this->belongsToMany(InterestsProperties::class, 'foreign_key');
    }

    public static function lgpdInterestsUser($id_user, $action)
    {
        if ($action == 'search') {
            $data = InterestsUser::where('user_id', $id_user)->get();

            if (count($data) > 0) {
                return $data;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } elseif ($action == 'delete') {
            $data = InterestsUser::with('properties')->where('user_id', $id_user)->get();

            foreach ($data->properties as $p) $p->delete();

            if ($data > 0) {
                return 'Success Remove.';
            } else {
                return 'Not Found.';
            }
        } else {
            return "Action Incorrect!";
        }
    }
}
```

##### `InterestsProperties.php`

```
class InterestsProperties extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Interests_Properties';    
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public $timestamps = false;        
}
```

The error is occurring when trying to remove with cascade:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::foreign()

Table Structure

- **`Interests_User`**

  - `id`
  - `interest_id`
  - `user_id`
  - `created_at`
  - `updated_at`
- **`Interests_Properties`**

  - `id`
  - `interests_user_id`
  - `key`
  - `value`
  - `created_at`
  - `updated_at`

Comment: This `->foreign('interests_user_id')->references('id')->on('Interests_Properties')->onDelete('cascade');` chain to create a FK in a migration not to fetch the pivot.

Comment: and how can I delete the model?

Comment: You need to remove all ref to the user in your table Interests_Properties. If you want to use the cascade you need to alter the DB, if not you can manually get all ref `InterestsUser::with('properties')->where('user_id', $id_user)` and then use regular delete on the refs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At DB level, using [onDelete](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints): when migrating your `InterestsProperties` model you'll have a line like

```
$table->foreignId('foreign_key')
```

to that add `->onDelete('cascade')`
after that update each time you delete a record from the main table it will do it in this one to.

At PHP level,

```
$data = InterestsUser::with('properties')->where('user_id', $id_user)->first();
foreach($data->properties as $p) $p->delete();
```

PD: Those will remove the property record too.

Comment: at php level I tried to run this code the error below occurred.                                                         {"error":{"code":503,"message":"Internal Server Error.","error":"Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null - \/var\/www\/api-subscriptions\/vendor\/illuminate\/database\/Eloquent\/Builder.php - 555"}}

Comment: the arg is `id_usuario` and in the query `id_user`

Comment: I had already fixed this, when I ran and received the error.

I updated the script as it is now.

Comment: Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null - \/var\/www\/api-subscriptions\/vendor\/illuminate\/database\/Eloquent\/Builder.php

Comment: InterestsUser has only with user_id or more?

Comment: change the get for a first `->where('user_id', $id_user)->first();`

Comment: The error continues.

The Interest_User table has more than one value with the same user_id

Comment: addEagerConstraints() on null yet